# Compare two channel field name

Tags: channel

I have a scenario I have two channels A and channel B. Both channel has one common select optional field let say c_a (option1,option2...option2) and b_a (option1,option2...option2)  . I want to compare the selective field when both selective option match then show the desire data.

Comment: Could you clean up this question up a little? It's formatting is of very poor quality.

Comment: For example, I have no idea what context you want a comparison triggered. In a template? A custom module you curl? The Control Panel?

Comment: Thanks jrothafer let me explain from practical life. i have two channel Candidate and Youtube_video. In candidate channel i have one selective field with drop down option in which specific  area is  assigned to candidate. In youtube_video channel user upload videos it also has onel selective field with drop down option in which user select from the option that in which area there video shoud be viewed.I have page in which single candidate data can be viewed.what i want here is i want to deploy youtube videos to show if its youtube selected area is selected to candidate area theshow videos

Comment: Ok.. that at least added some information... could you please review the help center to understand how to ask questions we can answer? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask And please **edit** your question, don't add comments as edits.

Comment: Fields of candidate channel
https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/289488/To6hwswXy4K9vSZ3a07JRd4PKXkwaJI8/ field name {constituency}
Fields of youtube_video channel
https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/289488/To6hwswXy4K9vSZ3a07JRd4PKXkwaJI8/ field name {video_constituency}
Both dropdown data is same line.
I have template page shows view in which i can see the single candidate data.its image , title and biography.what i want below is that if the user uploaded video select its area then video is shown below its data if not then nothing shows. thats it

Comment: Have you looked into using EE "Relationships: functionality?

Comment: I am beginner  in EE can you give me logic for that.